# 2.5 V and 3.3 V on Raspberry Pi 3 MOSI line

Tags: spi

I'm trying to read a SPI sensor via the raspberry pi, but I seem to be getting strange voltage levels on the MOSI line and no response on the MISO line.  The chip-select line and clock lines make sense.

[image]

The kernel module appears loaded:

```
$ ls -l /dev/spi* 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root spi 153, 0 Aug  8 09:17 /dev/spidev0.0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root spi 153, 1 Aug  8 09:17 /dev/spidev0.1
$ lsmod | grep spi
spidev                 20480  0
spi_bcm2835            20480  0
$ modinfo spidev
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.57-v7+/kernel/drivers/spi/spidev.ko
alias:          spi:spidev
license:        GPL
description:    User mode SPI device interface
author:         Andrea Paterniani, <a.paterniani@swapp-eng.it>
srcversion:     4EE702C8B42456520F93538
alias:          of:N*T*CspidevC*
alias:          of:N*T*Cspidev
alias:          of:N*T*Csemtech,sx1301C*
alias:          of:N*T*Csemtech,sx1301
alias:          of:N*T*Cge,achcC*
alias:          of:N*T*Cge,achc
alias:          of:N*T*Clineartechnology,ltc2488C*
alias:          of:N*T*Clineartechnology,ltc2488
alias:          of:N*T*Crohm,dh2228fvC*
alias:          of:N*T*Crohm,dh2228fv
depends:        
intree:         Y
name:           spidev
vermagic:       4.19.57-v7+ SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8 
parm:           bufsiz:data bytes in biggest supported SPI message (uint)
```

I don't get any errors on initializing the module:

```
import spidev

class RpiSpi():

    BUS_SPEED_HZ = 100000
    MODE = 0

    def __init__(self, bus, device):
        # Enable SPI
        self._spi = spidev.SpiDev()

        # Open a connection to a specific device (chip-select pin)
        # and bus.  There are two buses available.
        self._spi.open(bus, device)

        # Set SPI speed and mode
        self._spi.max_speed_hz = RpiSpi.BUS_SPEED_HZ
        self._spi.mode = RpiSpi.MODE

    def write_reg(self, reg, value):
        self._spi.xfer2([reg, value])

    def read_reg(self, reg):
        response = self._spi.xfer2([reg, 0x00])
        return response[1]

sensor = RpiSpi()
sensor.write_reg(0x70, 0b01000000)
while True:
   time.sleep(1)
   print(sensor.read_reg(0x75))
```

I've tried all permutations of mode and bus/device combos.

The MOSI line on an oscilloscope looks weird (2.5 V in some places when I would expect 3.3 V):

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2

spidev module documentation: http://tightdev.net/SpiDev_Doc.pdf

Pinout:
[image]

Comment: Most likely an error using the oscilloscope.  Wrong probes?  What is connected to the SPI bus?  Do connected devices operate properly.  More detail of the circuits please.

Comment: I would suggest to first try SPI loopback test to make sure Rpi SPI hardware and wiring is OK, before testing the sensor: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97869/how-to-check-if-spi-is-enabled-and-functional-on-raspi-3b

(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96225/why-is-spi-not-working-on-any-of-my-raspis

Answer (score 1):

This problem was sensor-dependent, thanks.  It turned out I needed to control the power sequencing so that I could put it into SPI mode instead of I2C mode very soon after powering on the sensor.