# Raspbi spi CS line won't drive low

Tags: pi-2, spi

Raspberry pi 2 Model B V1.1

Not sure what's happening here, everything should work. Tried different cables, different pins on the analyzer, different laptop... the CE0 line won't go low.

Currently MOSI sends bits and the clock is activated so I can only assume that the clock select is driving low.

I have wired up according to [image: this] diagram...

EDIT: adding wiring for completeness

Pin 19 - GPIO10 -> MOSI
Pin 21 - GPIO09 -> MISO
Pin 23 - GPIO11 -> CLK
Pin 24 - GPIO8   -> CEO_N
Pin 26 - GPIO7   -> CE1_N

I have tried using the CE1_N pin (according to above diagram), I have tried setting the alternate function on the pin, I even tried turning autocs off and manually driving a gpio (which is actually working).

Is there a step I'm missing? Is this diagram accurate? I don't think I need to set alternate functionality as the other SPI lines seem to work just fine.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  // If you call this, it will not actually access the GPIO
  // Use for testing
  // bcm2835_set_debug(1);

  if (!bcm2835_init()){
      printf("bcm2835_init failed. Are you running as root??\n");
      return 1;
  }

  if (!bcm2835_spi_begin()){
      printf("bcm2835_spi_begin failed. Are you running as root??\n");
      return 1;
  }

  bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);      // The default

    //Set SPI data mode
    //  BCM2835_SPI_MODE0 = 0,  // CPOL = 0, CPHA = 0
    //  BCM2835_SPI_MODE1 = 1,  // CPOL = 0, CPHA = 1
    //  BCM2835_SPI_MODE2 = 2,  // CPOL = 1, CPHA = 0
    //  BCM2835_SPI_MODE3 = 3,  // CPOL = 1, CPHA = 1
  //(SPI_MODE_# | SPI_CS_HIGH)=Chip Select active high, (SPI_MODE_# | SPI_NO_CS)=1 device per bus no Chip Select
  //
  bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0); // The default is mode0

    //Set SPI clock speed
  //
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_65536 = 0,       ///< 65536 = 262.144us = 3.814697260kHz (total H+L clock period)
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_32768 = 32768,   ///< 32768 = 131.072us = 7.629394531kHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_16384 = 16384,   ///< 16384 = 65.536us = 15.25878906kHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_8192  = 8192,    ///< 8192 = 32.768us = 30/51757813kHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_4096  = 4096,    ///< 4096 = 16.384us = 61.03515625kHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_2048  = 2048,    ///< 2048 = 8.192us = 122.0703125kHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_1024  = 1024,    ///< 1024 = 4.096us = 244.140625kHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_512   = 512,     ///< 512 = 2.048us = 488.28125kHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_256   = 256,     ///< 256 = 1.024us = 976.5625MHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_128   = 128,     ///< 128 = 512ns = = 1.953125MHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_64    = 64,      ///< 64 = 256ns = 3.90625MHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_32    = 32,      ///< 32 = 128ns = 7.8125MHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_16    = 16,      ///< 16 = 64ns = 15.625MHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_8     = 8,       ///< 8 = 32ns = 31.25MHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_4     = 4,       ///< 4 = 16ns = 62.5MHz
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_2     = 2,       ///< 2 = 8ns = 125MHz, fastest you can get
    //  BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_1     = 1,       ///< 1 = 262.144us = 3.814697260kHz, same as 0/65536
  //
  bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_64); 
  bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0); // The default is CS0

    //Set CS pins polarity to low
    //bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, 0);
    //bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS1, 0);
  //
  bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, 0);  // the default

  printf("Transferring 10 bytes... ");
  //Transfer n many bytes
    char data_buffer[10];
    int Count;
    for (Count = 0; Count < 10; Count++){
    data_buffer[Count] = 0x80 + Count;
  }
    bcm2835_spi_transfern(&data_buffer[0], 10);         //data_buffer used for tx and rx
  printf("done\n");

  // OR Send a byte to the slave and simultaneously read a byte back from the slave
  // If you tie MISO to MOSI, you should read back what was sent
  //uint8_t send_data = 0x23;
  //uint8_t read_data = bcm2835_spi_transfer(send_data);
  //printf("Sent to SPI: 0x%02X. Read back from SPI: 0x%02X.\n", send_data, read_data);

  //check data if doing loopback test
  //if (send_data != read_data){
  //    printf("Do you have the loopback from MOSI to MISO connected?\n");
  //}

  printf("Closing spi... ");

  bcm2835_spi_end();
  bcm2835_close();

  printf("done\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I have a simple plug-and-play python troubleshooting program to test two things: (1) loopback, (2) repeat send bytes: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97869/how-to-check-if-spi-is-enabled-and-functional-on-raspi-3b/97876#97876. For the repeat send byte function, you can see with a scope if CS is driving low.  If you don't have a scope, perhaps you can try to see with a multi-meter if the output is about half of 3V3.

Comment: Or you can try the other SPI bus: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99079/using-two-spi-ports-simultaneously-on-raspberry-pi-0-w.  My second demo program shows SPI2's CE2 also working.  In other words you can check out SPI1's CE0, CE1, and SPI2's CE2.

Comment: My answer to this question shows the SPI waveforms: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96225/why-is-spi-not-working-on-any-of-my-raspis

Comment: How do you know the chip select doesn't go low?  If it doesn't go low there are three possibilities, 1) it is bust, 2) something is holding it high, 3) you are not telling it to go low.  WE NEED photos of the wiring.

Comment: Added a basic wiring plot as cannot upload photo. Upon further reflection, perhaps you are right: I'm not actually telling it to go low. Is the 'N' in 'CE0_N' supposed to signify something? Do I need to manually tell the CS pin to drive low? If so, why would I need to define the CS pin in the first place? I suppose that is a question for the bcm2835 library developer.

Comment: @tlfong01 thanks, I'll try those tests when I get home.

Comment: @BitShift The hardware will properly assert the chip select (low) provided it is in the correct mode.  I guess the bcm2835_spi_begin will set the correct mode.  However you might confuse the issue if you set it to a different mode within the program or outside the program. `sudo pigpiod; pigs spio 0 50000 0; pigs spix 0 1 2 3 4 5` should toggle the enable pin (GPIO 8, pin 24).

Comment: Rock and roll, I'll test that when I get home. Thanks for the help, I'll update if any further issues :)